# PHP debugging with CodeIgniter MacGDBp and Xdebug on MAMP

Tags: debugging, codeigniter, xdebug, mamp

Fellow Coders, i downloaded Xdebug and MacGDBp. installed them tried to debug a CodeIgniter 1.7 Controller. here is what happens:

- Xdebug and Macgdbp can talk.
- execution stops at the beginning of index.php
- i can step through index.php

the issue I have is that i cannot get the debugger to recognize and therefore stop at any breakpoint i set in any other php file. It only seems to debug index.php and the other php files it calls. Nothing i do in the breakpoint window seems to have any effect.

my config:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

One other note, my php.ini did not have any reference to the zend optimizer as some installation instructions say that i have to comment out.  I'm using php 5.3.2.

has anyone been able to debug CI code with these tools? any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I havent use the debugger you mentioned, however I have been using Zend studio and zend community server to debug codeigniter application , for this you need to install zend studio toolbar for firefox or IE. Using the zend browser toolbar feature you can directly debug from the browser and setting a break point through zend editor.

Comment: I have given up on Xdebug and MacGDBp. started playing with zend studio. looks promising.  thanks for the response.